# forgot my pattern for lock screen

Tags: screen, pattern-lock

I'm locked out of my tablet because I can't remember what my screen lock pattern is. How do I reset factory settings if I can't get into the tablet?
please help this is all new to me

Answer (score 0):

Boot into your Recovery in this way:

1. Shut down your device
2. Google for "(your device name) recovery"
3. In your recovery you can perform a factory reset.